# wxToolBar with dynamically sized buttons

Tags: wxwidgets

My application (Microsoft Windows only) is using a wxToolBar with `wxTB_HORIZONTAL|wxTB_TEXT|wxTB_HORZ_LAYOUT` flags set. All it's buttons/tools have the same width, which is based on the longest text.

I'd like to have buttons with different widths, depending on the tool label's length, just like the Windows native toolbar buttons (created with the `BTNS_AUTOSIZE` style).

Is there any way to get wxToolBar with buttons that have dynamically calculated width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want this for MS Windows, since you mention the *BTNS_AUTOSIZE* style.

There is no way to do this with *wxToolBar* styles or a parameter to *AddTool()*. I have tried with wxMSW, and the only way to achieve auto-sizing buttons (that I could find) is by changing the *wxToolBar::Realize()* method in *src/msw/tbar95.cpp* (*src/msw/toolbar.cpp* in wxWidgets trunk) to add the *BTNS_AUTOSIZE* style in the places where the buttons are added. This is a virtual method, so you could always create your own descending toolbar class, copy the *Realize()* method and change it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought about creating descending class, but wanted to know if there is any simpler solution.